# wp_redirect function working locally, but not on server

Tags: wordpress

I'm using code directly from this tutorial: http://voodoopress.com/how-to-post-from-your-front-end-with-no-plugin/. When set up locally the redirect works fine. When the exact same site is hosted on a rackspace cloud site, it doesn't. What's going on?

Notable piece:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {

// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter the wine name';
}
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter some notes';
}

$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'post_content'  =>  $description,
'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
'tags_input'    =>  array($tags),
'post_status'   =>  'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
'post_type' =>  'post'  //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
);

//SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

         //SET OUR TAGS UP PROPERLY
wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);

//REDIRECT TO THE NEW POST ON SAVE
$link = get_permalink( $pid );
wp_redirect( $link );

} // END THE IF STATEMENT THAT STARTED THE WHOLE FORM

//POST THE POST YO
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');`
```

It's pretty straightforward. The code is posting a post using `wp_insert_post` and redirecting to that post's link afterward. All well and good, and it works on my XAMPP setup. But here's the issue: I can't get any permutation of this to work on a live server. I've started with fresh WP installs several times, only placing this code in a home.php, and to no avail. Any idea as to what the heck could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought, is there any white space above the redirect in any of your pages? Redirects must be called before any white space or other elements are added to the page so if you are echoing something before your redirect it will not work.

Comment: That's a good thought, but it's a `wp_redirect` called after a `POST` so I think that doesn't apply.